# Hive managed table drop doesn't delete files on HDFS. Any solutions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, azure-databricks

While deleting managed tables from the hive, its associated files from hdfs are not being removed (on azure-databricks). I am getting the following error:

> [Simba]SparkJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can not create the managed table('`schema`.`XXXXX`'). The associated location('dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/schema.db/XXXXX) already exists

This issue is occurring intermittently. Looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Databricks does not offer Hadoop/Hive, where is your data located? Perhaps in HDP/CDH/HDI with a certain version of Hive? Does the problem also occur when working on the cluster directly with its local Spark? -- Also, please add the exact commands to reproduce the situation. (Ideally from creation, to deletion and re-creation)

Comment: The issue states it's on Azure which uses blob storage and Azure VMs. Furthermore it's spark and so assume 2.xxx version of spark which has Hive packaged into it. It's not a Hive deployment perse but spark includes Hive and should work. Databricks is a supported and managed spark service so this shouldn't be happening on managed spark tables (which are Hive tables).

Answer (score 3):

I've started hitting this. It was fine for the last year then something is going on with the storage attachment I think. Perhaps enhancements going on in the back ground that are causing issues (PaaS!) As a safeguard I'm manually deleting the directly path as well dropping the table until I can get a decent explanation of what's going on or get a support call answered.

Use

```
dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/schema.db/XXXXX", true)
```

becarefull with that though! Get the path wrong and it could be tragic!

Answer (score 0):

So sometimes the metadata(schema info of Hive table) itself gets corrupted. So whenever we try to delete/drop the table we get errors as, spark checks for the existance of the table before deleting.

We can avoid that if we use hive clint to drop the table, as it avoids checking the table's existence.

[Please refer this wonder databricks documentation](https://kb.databricks.com/metastore/drop-table-corruptedmetadata.html)